# Alignment issue for "questions that may already have your answer"

Tags: bug, questions, design

When asking a new question the list of "Questions that may already have your answer" contains questions with (green rectangle) and without accepted answers. As you can see these types or question has different indent:

> [image: has answer]

Related only for Stack Overflow sites (localized and metas too).

For those who couldn't see a problem: the lines with no accepted answers are slightly shifted to the left (score and title). On Meta.SE this defect does not exist

Comment: Just curious. What's happening? What's expected? I can't find anything crazy or wrong with this. I checked it in Stack Overflow and MSE, both gives me the same result like you have posted. What are you expecting?

Comment: @PraveenKumar lines with no accepted answers are slightly shifted to the left (score and title). On Meta.SE this defect is not exists.

Comment: Ah, now I see it... Man, that's so small, looks like there's an extra spacing or some kinda `inline-block` issue. Nice find.

Comment: [Have you ever seen this image?  How does it make you feel?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That inconsistent alignment appears to be a consequence of this CSS rule:

```
.answered, .answered-accepted {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Disabling it makes the misalignment disappear, but shrinks the "accepted" bubble:

[image: correctly aligned]

Moving the `border: 1px solid transparent;` into the `.answer-votes` rule corrects the misalignment and keeps the bubbles nice and large:

[image: fixed]