# Way to promote a specific fix or feature request to be implemented by developers

Tags: discussion

Some unfixed bugs or feature requests have had many upvotes for a long time, but are still not implemented. I would like to know is there a way to expedite such implementation.

For ordinary questions on any site you can start a bounty to draw additional attention. But what if you want to see a bug report or feature request [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) here on Stack Exchange? Per-site metas don't have bounties. Also, while MSE has bounties, as far as I can see SE employees don't want my rep.

Probably if we could start some crowdfunding project, to fund our own community developer, who would make what we want in order to make the SE network better for us. What do you think about it?

Some small bugs are annoying for me; in several cases there are already answers from other users how to implement fixes. There is even the [SOUP patch](https://stackapps.com/q/4486), which offers client-side fixes for over a hundred bugs across the network packaged in a handy user script. The author has specifically given permission for any of those fixes to be incorporated into the SE code base. But neither of these happen and I don't know the reason.

The SE team [has stated](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7828/typo-in-reputation-recalc-error-message#comment20032_7828) that they prefer that even trivial issues be reported, as they are "super easy and trivial to fix".

Comment: @rene where I can put my money for it?

Comment: At the VC desk ...

Comment: Your question title has little to do with having a special developer in your pocket... what do you actually want?

Comment: @rene what is this?

Comment: @Catija the last paragraph.

Comment: I don't really see how that makes sense... why would SO allow someone they're not able to direct to have access to their code base to know how to change it?

Comment: @Catija I mean some dev inside SO, but receiving a salary from community.

Comment: @alexolut With VC I meant Venture Capitalist. The companies that only invest for a minimum of 10 million dollars.

Comment: Companies really can't work well with staff who have divided priorities. They either need their staff doing what they need them to do... or they don't.

Comment: I feel this question is related to [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange)

Comment: I think you should check out my answer on the duplicate target.

Answer (score 5):

When the code compiles, it's about 20% done.  Maybe 10%.  The fact that somebody has posted a userscript to change a behavior is *helpful*, but far from sufficient.

Some additional things that need to happen:

- Design review.  That it's the behavior that *you* or *I* want doesn't mean it's right for all of SE's users.  Somebody needs to review for generality, UX, localization considerations, behavior in different browsers and at different sizes, accessibility, how well it plays with different sites' designs, etc.
- Code review, including performance and security (does this new code leak anything out of the DB that ought not be leaked?).
- Testing.
- Other impacts.  Does this change require corresponding changes to the mobile (web) interface, apps, the API?

Now sometimes a user-submitted change really is nearly ready to go out of the box.  Mi Yodeya has a Hebrew keyboard that was written by one of our users as a userscript and then adapted as a built-in feature (on selected sites) by SE.  It *can* happen.  But you can't assume that just because there's code, it's easy for SE to stick it in the code base for everybody.

So, how to prioritize?  Well, SE's devs get their priorities from lots of different sources -- product management, the community team, internal initiatives, user feedback, and presumably funders.  The best we can do is to make a strong case and draw attention.  The strongest cases demonstrate some awareness of and consideration for all these other factors beyond just writing the code.  In your feature request, be sure to describe *the actual problem you're trying to solve* (not just the implementation you want), what approaches you considered, why you think this is the right approach, how it interacts with all those design things I mentioned, etc.

**Addendum** after question edit: I do think that widely-used, minor bug fixes like those in SOUP should be considered by the team because they've been user-tested in a variety of settings and there's active maintenance.  That's different from somebody posting code in an answer and saying "use this".

Comment: Does it really hard to fix such small things like these: [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288893/339911), [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290971/339911), [three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292228/339911), [four](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289705/339911)? All of them contain a possible solution.

Comment: @alexolut why should such minor cosmetic issues be priorities?

Comment: @RobertLongson because they annoying and I see them everyday. Just imagine what would you say if there was a typo in “Stack Overglow” logo. Design issues is a face of the company, it should be well-groomed.

Comment: @alexolut Fixing them means that the developers are not fixing something more important is my point. This is called [opportunity cost](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/opportunitycost.asp)

Comment: Can you please give me feedback on my answer to the duplicate target?

Comment: @Ano that looks reasonable.  I agree with the comment about bounties for FRs, and I disagree on some minor points but overall, it's a good description.

Comment: @RobertLongson dev team could create Roadmap with priorities, so community can see, which tasks they are working on.